# Java - How decode CBOR encoded byte[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, cbor

I get data from server - is a CBOR encoded byte[] array and to decoded this I am using [cbor-java](https://github.com/c-rack/cbor-java) implementation.

```
    byte[] decodedMessage = { 0x78, (byte)0x9c, 0x5b, (byte)0xe4, 0x58, 0x10}
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedMessage);
    List<DataItem> dataItems = new CborDecoder(bais).decode();
    for(DataItem dataItem : dataItems) {
    }
```

If you have some experience with this, can you explain me how i can get the decoded content of array, not the [DataItem](http://c-rack.github.io/cbor-java/apidocs/index.html) object.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I use answer bellow, and adapt it for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataItem is already very close to what you want. First you need to check which type the DataItem is:

```
for (DataItem dataItem : dataItems) {
    System.out.println("the type of this dataItem is " + dataItem.getMajorType());
    switch(dataItem.getMajorType()) {
        UNSIGNED_INTEGER:
            UnsignedInteger unsignedInteger = (UnsignedInteger) dataItem;
            System.out.println("the value of this dataItem is " + unsigendInteger.getValue());
        /* ... add missing ones */
        default:
            System.out.println("unknown type: " + dataItem.getMajorType());
    }
}
```

With that you can read the data that is inside your byte array.
You just need to adapt it for the values you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [jackson-dataformats-binary](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary)? The library has [very good performance](http://richardstartin.uk/concise-binary-object-representation/) and is just like working with JSON.